# SQL Server : incorrect syntax near '@'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been searching the net whole day but I don't know what is the keyword to search for the solution so ended up I am here.

Here is a piece of my sample SQL query:

```
DECLARE @column_name varchar(50)
SET @column_name = 'test'

SELECT
    t1.@column_name,
    t2.@column_name
FROM 
    table_test AS t1  
INNER JOIN 
    table_test2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```

Running this query, I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@column_name'.

near `t1.@column_name` and `t2.@column_name`.

How do I solve this error? I've been trying putting brackets around but still doesn't work.

Comment: You can't parameterize names of things in the database. You will have to generate the right SQL using strings instead.

Comment: Where SQL Server is expecting you to give it a *name*, you're instead giving it a *string* (contained in a variable). These are *not* the same things.

Comment: So is there any another way to make things works? I am quite new to SQL that's why.

Comment: If you need to dynamically define column names in this way, then you probably have a database modelling issue

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid because im actually fetching column name from information_schema table using a cursor. so it is return as such format. this is the way i figure out myself, unless you have a better solution :)

Comment: OK well that is a reasonable use of dynamic column names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use Dynamic SQL to achieve this. This uses the `sys` objects, as it's VERY important you avoid SQL Injection.

```
DECLARE @column_name varchar(50)
SET @column_name = 'test'

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = N'
SELECT t1.' + QUOTENAME(c.[name])
FROM sys.tables t
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.[name] = 'table_test'
  AND c.[name] = @column_name;

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'
       t2.'+ QUOTENAME(c.[name])
FROM sys.tables t
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.[name] = 'table_test2'
  AND c.[name] = @column_name;

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'
FROM table_test t1
     JOIN Tabletest_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;';

PRINT @SQL;
--EXEC sp_executesql @SQL; --Uncomment to run the SQL
```

Please ask if you don't understand any of this.

Comment: Ok, tried using your way and works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand what it's doing? The importance of avoiding SQL Injection for Dynamic SQL is huge. I'm happy to explain it.

Comment: just to inform you that the line `JOIN Tabletest_2 ON t1.id = t2.id;'; ` has a slight code error, you forget to assign t2 to Tabletest_2 :)

Comment: Thanks @ChuahChengJun will amend. :)

Comment: yeap, i am aware the importance of avoiding SQL injection, but since this piece of code is running locally, shouldn't be a huge problem as it is not publicize

Comment: correct me if im wrong, basically you are comparing back the table and column name with the sys.table and sys.columns. basically if anyone tries to inject anything, this piece of SQL query wont run as it doesnt return the desire value after validating from the sys.table and column

Comment: Correct. The column has to exist in both the tables `table_test` and `table_test2`. If it doesn't, then either the first or second `SELECT` statement will return `NULL`, resulting in `@SQL` having the value `NULL`. Thus, `sp_executesql` doesn't run anything. :) Glad to see you understand.